# Ubuntu 18.04: mic stopped working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Suddenly today I tried to audio call, but my mic didn't work. I tried to change the settings according to the answers I've seen on SO and SE, but nothing worked. These are my current settings:

[image]

The

```
sudo pavucontrol
```

gives these settings:

[image]
[image]

[image]

(another option is `Microphone (plugged in)`)

[image]

I also tried to record an audio file using:

```
arecord test.wav
```

the file gets created, but it's several seconds of no sound.

Any help is appreciated.